# Adding page:1 param to Sort link CakePHP 2.3

Tags: cakephp-2.3

Once I use CakePHP 2.3 sort link, it works, but doesn't change the url for page:1, it means if user now is in page:16, after clicking another sort link, he will be on page:16, but on different sorting - really confusing. When he was browsing results by date, reached 16 page and clicked sort by price and he is on 16 page sorting by price. Total confusion for User Interface. How to fix it? Thanks!

```
echo $this->Paginator->sort('title', 'Title', array('direction' => 'desc', 'page'=>1));
```

Answer (score 1):

I use a custom function like:

echo $this->MyHelper->sort(...);

In MyHelper class:

```
var $helpers = array('Paginator');
public function sort($key, $title = null, $options = array()) {
    $options['url'] = array('page' => 1);
    return $this->Paginator->sort($key, $title, $options);
}
```

Also, I would recommend to switch to querystring instead of named parameters using:

```
    'Paginator' => array(
        'limit' => 15,
        'paramType' => 'querystring'
    ),
```

when you define your components.